# List materials, which don't have a specific language key

Tags: select, abap

I'm pretty new to ABAP Coding. I got the task to realize a report that lists all materials, which don't have a specific language key. 
For example, the user enters in the selection screen "EN" as a language key. As a result, all materials, which don't have the language key "EN" should be displayed.
There are two tables: MARA (material data) and MAKT (language key = SPRAS), which are connected via the primary key (MATNR).

I tried it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM MARA INNER JOIN MAKT ON MARA~MATNR EQ MAKT~MATNR WHERE MAKT~SPRAS NOT IN S_SPRAS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that S_SPRAS is select-option with multi-choice.
In that case if you need to display materials which have none of specified languages, use this:

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE lt_mara
FROM MARA
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MAKT WHERE MAKT~MATNR = MARA~MATNR AND MAKT~SPRAS IN S_SPRAS )
```

If you need to display materials which don't have at least one of specified languages, it is just more complex and depends on your runtime version - higher 7.50 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following SQL statement with LEFT JOIN

```
select mara~matnr
into table @data(gt_matnr)
from mara
left JOIN makt
  on MAKT~MATNR = MARA~MATNR and
     MAKT~SPRAS = @s_spras-low
where MAKT~MATNR IS null.
```